# Panorama graph using gephi

Tags: opencv, graph, panoramas, image-stitching, gephi

I'm saving graph in .DOT language format using opencv stitching module.

```
ofstream f("graph.dot");
f << matchesGraphAsString(img_names, pairwise_matches, conf_thresh);
f.close();
```

I can plot this graph using gephi, but how can I plot confidence of connection on edge of the graph and img at vertex of graph?